# how to move ssh-key related files to another directory?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, ssh-keys, fish, dotfiles

i've been trying to clean up my *root* directory so that it isn't clustered with random *dotfiles*. nonetheless, on setting up the *ssh-key* i came to a dead-end, where i wouldn't find a way to migrate *known_hosts* file to the other direction (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/`).

i used this command to generate my ssh-key:

```shell
mkdir -p $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my@email.com" -f $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/id_ed25519
```

but yet i need to create a `~/.ssh/config` file to point at my `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/config` file, which is frustrating because i want to get rid of the `~/.ssh` directory

i used several approaches one of them was to set an env var `SSH_CONFIG` to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/config` but that didn't work either

⚠️ i'm using **macOS** and **fish shell** to prevent confusion

this is the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/` directory structure:

```
config
id_ed25519
id_ed25519.pub
known_hosts #this file is ignored as ssh expects its in ~/.ssh/
```

this is the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/config` file:

```yaml
GlobalKnownHostsFile $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/known_hosts #this doesn't help either 
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/id_ed25519
```

and the current fix that is working, is only creating a `.ssh/config` with the value `UserKnownHostsFile $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/known_hosts`, which makes my whole migration of the files pointless.

`.ssh/config` file:

```yaml
UserKnownHostsFile $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ssh/known_hosts
```

is there something that i'm missing?

how can i fix this?

or is there a better way of organising one selfs root folder?

i tried to set the env var `SSH_CONFIG` but it seems to ignore it:

```shell
set -Ux SSH_CONFIG ~/.config/ssh/config #fish syntax, it's the same as: export SSH_CONFIG="$HOME/.config/ssh/config"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post
[How can you change the default location of the .ssh folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/11029/how-can-you-change-the-default-location-of-the-ssh-folder)
has this
[answer by Binita Bharati](https://serverfault.com/a/1096486/18736):

> To change the default location for the `.ssh` directory, you can edit
> the below settings:
>
> 1. /etc/ssh/ssh_config: Edit the value for `IdentityFile`. A sample entry would look like this: `IdentityFile /es2/ssh/id_rsa`. Here
>    `/es2/ssh` is the desired directory to keep the public and private
>    keys.
> 2. /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Update the value for `AuthorizedKeysFile`, A sample entry would look like this: `AuthorizedKeysFile  /es2/ssh/authorized_keys`
>
> Also, do not forget to restart your ssh daemon after making this
> config updates.

Reference :
[sshd_config(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).